# What are character vectors made of?

Tags: r, string

`"Alice"` is a character vector of length 1. `"Bob"` is also a character vector of length 1, but it's clearly shorter. At face value, it appears that R's character are made out of something smaller than characters, but if you try to subset them, say `"Alice"[1]`, you'll just get the original vector back. How does R internally make sense of this? What are character vectors actually made of?

Comment: If yoou need to split up the vector `substr("Bob", 1, 1)` or get the number of characters `nchar("Bob")`

Comment: @akrun I know, but that's not what I'm interested in.

Comment: A character vector is a vector of strings (which are values of type `character`). Arguably, `character` is misnamed in R (calling it `string` would have been clearer for people coming from other programming languages), but it is what it is.

Comment: each string is made of  a character it can be even digits too "Bob1".  Regarding your subset comment `"Alice"[1]`, it is considered as a single unit. In python, it would give you 'l'

Comment: Internally the C code that R is written in considers a "character vector" to be a collection of pointers to strings in the global string pool. If you really want to know how R deals with these things, you might be interested in [R's C interface](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html). But that's pretty low level to be of practical use.

Comment: @akrun "You're mistaking vector length for string length." was the valuable part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistaking **vector** length for **string** length.

In R common variables are all vectors containing whatever data you typed, so both are vectors that contain 1 string even if you don't assign a name to them.

If you want to check the size of each string, use nchar function:

```
nchar("Alice")
[1] 5
nchar("Bob")
[1] 3
```